# Permanently set Process Priority with PID?

Tags: windows-11

I haven't found an answer if it's possible and how to set the process priority of a program using the PID value, only with the program name [like shown here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-permanently-set-priority-processes-using/df82bd40-ce52-4b84-af34-4d93da17d079). Using Windows 11.

I'm playing a game with multiple game clients, so I need a way to differentiate between them, as they all share the same program name.

I was thinking the PID value should do it? Any other way would be great too.

Also whether it's permanent or need to do it each time - both are fine!

Comment: An app doesn't have a PID until it launches - then it's different every time.

Comment: PID won't do it. you will have to look for a different determining factor, or if you are working with a scripting language that provides the PID when it launches a process, you can write a script to invoke your clients, record their PIDs, and in the process set their priority.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply.


But is there something I can do manually after each time it launches?

Let's say I have 4 game clients open already, is there a way now to change their "process priority" with the PID? Maybe in the example I link above but with PID?

Because the problem is in this game each time you load a different area, the 'process priority' keeps setting itself on high, which causes freezes. I can manually change it each time in Task Manager but it's too much of a hassle.

If a way to change it just once and stay like that after I open the clients, it would be great!